# Using select options xeditable angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-xeditable

I am trying to edit table which contains a select drop-down menu. For that, I am using xeditable for angularjs.
My HTML file containt: `<td><span editable-select="awsendpoint.organizationName" e-name="organizationName" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="organization.organizationName for organization in getallorganization">{{awsendpoint.organizationName}}</span></td>`

getallorganization = `[{ "name":"John1", "organizationName":"ORG1", "city":"New York" },{ "name":"John2", "organizationName":"ORG2", "city":"New York" },{ "name":"John3", "organizationName":"ORG3", "city":"New York" }]`

The drop-down menu is showing in table and edit mode.

The problem here is during `update` the data. When I am trying to update the table data. Updated "organizationName" field is showing the whole `organization` object and the data is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the value to be one property from your `getallorganization`, then you need to set that in the `e-ng-options`.

E.g. `e-ng-options="organization.organizationName as organization.name for organization in getallorganization"`